# ImportCardinalityMismatchException when using RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes with PRISM MEF

Tags: c#, prism, mef

when I override RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes and I try to register my own WCServiceAgent the Bootstrapper throws a

```
ImportCardinalityMismatchException
Additional information: No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName    Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator
RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator
```

The exception occurs with:

```
 protected override void RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes()
    {
        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<IModuleCatalog>(this.ModuleCatalog);
        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<AggregateCatalog>(this.AggregateCatalog);
    }
```

and also with

```
    protected override void RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes()
    {
         this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<MyWCFServiceAgent>(new MyWCFServiceAgent(1));
    }
```

in my Bootstrapper class

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    //protected override void RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes()
    //{
    //see above code
    //}

    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<ShellWindow>();
    }
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
    }
    protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
    {
        var factory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();
        //factory.AddIfMissing("AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior", typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior));
        return factory;
    }
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return base.CreateModuleCatalog();
    }
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? Whats the cause of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the base implementation first.

```
protected override void RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes()
{
    base.RegisterBootstrapperProvidedTypes();

    // your custom registrations go here...        
}
```

If you take a look at the [implementation](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Desktop/Prism.MefExtensions/MefBootstrapper.cs) of the bootstrapper base class, you'll see that there are 4 exports which need to be composed:

```
this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<ILoggerFacade>(this.Logger);
this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<IModuleCatalog>(this.ModuleCatalog);
this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<IServiceLocator>(new MefServiceLocatorAdapter(this.Container));
this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<AggregateCatalog>(this.AggregateCatalog);
```